# Python: *args, grouped by type

Tags: python

I have a class `__init__` that accepts variable length arguments.  I am trying to figure out how to separate the `*args` into `str`, and `floats/ints`.

So, for example, in my mind that might look like:

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self, *legs, *vals, named_input: float, named_input_2: str):
```

`*legs` are a string.    `*vals` are floats & ints.

My goal is that the user can do:

```
a = Example('1y', '5y', named_input = 100, named_input_2 = 'setting_1')
a.legs = ['1y', '5y']
a.vals = []

a = Example('1y', '5y', 15, named_input = 100, named_input_2 = 'setting_1')
a.legs = ['1y', '5y']
a.vals = [15]

a = Example('1y', 0, 15, 30, named_input = 100, named_input_2 = 'setting_1')
a.legs = ['1y']
a.vals = [ 0, 15, 30,]
```

At least 1 `*leg` must always be supplied.  `vals` can be `None` though.

Comment: Use a function to seperate ints from strings then feed the __init__ method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overcomplicated it..  just had to do this:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.legs = []
        self.vals = []
        for x in args:
            if type(x) in [str]:
                self.legs.append(x)
            elif type(x) in  [float, int]:
                self.vals.append(x)
```